# USB extension cable messing me up

Tags: windows-10, usb, extension

So I bought a 3 meter long (~10 feet) USB extension cable for my Steinberg UR12 audio interface, because the cable was too short. But when I plugged in the cable, windows doesn't respond with anything, and when I went to check my device manager, my audio interface was labeled under: Generuc USB Hub. Please someone help me, I want to use my audio interface.

Comment: Sounds pretty indicative of a bad cable... If the device works without cable, then you connect the cable and device and everything falls apart, you likely have a bad cable.

Comment: But the thing is the cable works with my webcam tho, so it can't be the cable.

Comment: Is the connection USB 2.0 or 3.0?  If it's 3.0, the combined cable length is too long (unless you're using a custom cable, a single cable rated for 3 meters is the max length for a passive cable).  If it's 2.0, your combined length might still be within the 5 meter limit, but you're using an original cable and an add-on that may each be rated for their own length, so combining them is like using a cable that is too long.  You may need to use an active cable or add a powered hub before the extension cable if you need that length.

Comment: I'm using USB 2.0, and the combined lenght of the two cables is only 3,5 meters, so is that really too much? But again, it did work with my webcam (which also has a 0,5 meter cable).

Comment: @DontKnowWho Sure it can be the cable. "Good" vs "bad" is not necessarily a binary state; a cable can be "slightly bad" and still work with some devices but not others, because they have different thresholds / reliability requirements.

Comment: Does it work without the extension cable?

Comment: Did you try the self-powered mode (using u-USB external power supply)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the USB-cable is not faulty (since it works with another device this is most likely the case, but there's no guarantee), then the combined length of the cables and/or the connection between the two cables (or a combination of both) causes the issue. The USB-Signal from the UR12 device gets - simply speaking - too "weak" and/or "polluted with interference" which makes it unusable for Windows.

In this case you will have to use "active" device, for example an small USB-Hub (which has its own power supply). This, again simply speaking, sort of "stabilizes/enhances" the signal:

**[PC]<==usbcable1==>[USB-Hub]<==usbcable2==>[UR12]**

Note: there are also passive USB hubs/extensions without an additional power supply which are supposed amplify/clean the USB signal when used for extensions. But in my personal experience they don't work as reliable as the active ones.